# How to print SOAP message version of JAX-RPC service in websphere

Tags: java, client, websphere, jax-rpc

I want to print SOAP Message version of input header/request objects and response header/response objects. I am using stubs to call jax-rpc webservice( Eg:

```
GetPubKeyServiceImplServiceSoapBindingStub extends com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.client.Stub
```

Please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If getting it in a trace file is good enough, instructions are here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_tracewbscomp.html

If you need it as a string in memory, you'll need to add a handler to your client to capture the messages.

(JAX-RPC has been deprecated.)